# UTF-8 encoding and requiredMessage

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I need some JSF2 advice about requiredMessage. I tried to use my ResourceBundle by `<f:loadBundle basename="messages" var="msgs"/>`. In my particular local it contains cyrillic symbols. So, trying to use it in requiredMessage have no success:

```
<h:inputText id="id" value="#{myBean.val}" required="true" 
                      requiredMessage="latinКИРИЛЛ#{msgs['reqMsg']}">
```

Displayed message is just `latinКИРИЛЛ`.

The problem is that symbols written by hand (`КИРИЛЛ` in my case) is displayed in the message succesfully. But the `#{msgs['reqMsg']}` part is not displayed. If I just put `#{msgs['reqMsg']}` in a facelet it display the required message content as I specified in the bundle. But why isn't it displayed in the `requiredMessage`? I have really no idea about that. Why might it happen?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Mojarra 2.2.12.

Comment: @BalusC Hm... interesting. Looks like it's a configuration specific thing. Ok, I'll continue digging down.